# How to calculate time in c++?

Tags: c++, time.h

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate time in c++ . I'm making 
a program where every 3 seconds an event happens for example print out "hello" etc;

Comment: It depends on your event processing library.  C++ itself doesn't provide any event system, but in no event system I've ever used does knowing the system time and date help with setting a recurring event.

Comment: You can always make a thread that takes a function and loops, sleeping three seconds and calling it. That generalizes it more, and allows reuse. If I'm going to do that, though, take the time to sleep as well.

Comment: are you not just looking for a [sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) function ? strat a new thread and let it loop endlessly where you sleep for 3 seconds and print hello.

Comment: @A4L, Or `std::this_thread::sleep_for`, which is standard C++11.

Comment: I was thinking using difftime but sleep would be better right ?

Comment: if you need your thread to only fire an event every 3 seconds then `sleep` is what you need. use [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) as @chris suggests. using difference between two timestamps is not the right approach.

Comment: @user2253393: Sleeping is good. If you have nothing to do, you should sleep. (I'm actually talking about your program here!) In a multitasking environment (i.e. *everywhere*) you should sleep as much as you can. But remember one thing: you *can't* depend on the time you pass to sleep. If you ask to sleep for 3 seconds, you might get less or you might get more. What you should do is sleep for smaller amounts of time (say, half a second) and check to see whether a full 3 seconds has passed. If it has, do what you want to do and then sleep again.

Comment: If you know it is `3 seconds` exactly and this _must_ run at that interval, why not use `alarm()`? [man alarm](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm)

Comment: I believe sleep() will not work for my program. I'm making a game where a box flying around a screen drops another box every 3 seconds. But sleep pauses the program which is bad

Comment: `sleep` stops only the thread from witch is was called. other threads keep running. you don't imagine you could write your game with only one thread ???

Comment: So if i put sleep() on a fuction/method and every 3 seconds update the counter. It would not affect the whole program??

Comment: If that function is executed in a separate threat then the rest of the program will not be affected. have a look at the answers below to see how to create a new thread from your main thread or just ask google.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help;

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using two threads so your program won't freeze and `this_thread::sleep_for()` in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void hello()
{
    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
        chrono::milliseconds duration( 3000 );
        this_thread::sleep_for( duration );
    }
}

int main()
{
    //start the hello thread
    thread help1(hello);
    //do other stuff in the main thread
    for(int i=0; i <10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Hello2" << endl;
        chrono::milliseconds duration( 3000 );
        this_thread::sleep_for( duration );
    }
    //wait for the other thread to finish in this case wait forever(while(1))
    help1.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `boost::timer` to calculate time in C++:

```
using boost::timer::cpu_timer;
using boost::timer::cpu_times;
using boost::timer::nanosecond_type;
...
nanosecond_type const three_seconds(3 * 1000000000LL);

cpu_timer timer;


  cpu_times const elapsed_times(timer.elapsed());
  nanosecond_type const elapsed(elapsed_times.system + elapsed_times.user);
  if (elapsed >= three_seconds)
  {
    //more then 3 seconds elapsed
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is dependent on your OS/Compiler.

Case 1:
If you have C++11 then you can use as suggested by Chris:
std::this_thread::sleep_for() // You have to include header file thread

Case 2:
If you are on the windows platform then you can also use something like:

```
#include windows.h 
int main () 
{ 
    event 1; 
    Sleep(1000); // number is in milliseconds 1Sec = 1000 MiliSeconds 
    event 2; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Case 3:
On linux platform you can simply use:
sleep(In seconds);